# get first number from a string

Tags: c#, regex, substring

i have a string

> Ł9CZIA KUOTA PIV 1,21 SUMA 12,36 otóuka 2 | 0350 |tKasa 1

and i want to get first decimal number (with comma) after word **SUMA** (there might be more words between SUMA and number)

> 12,36

what is the easiest method to achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried? I see you added the regex tag. Have you done anything with that yet?

Comment: i tried with substring and regex, but i only managed to get string after SUMA and then first 6 characters

Comment: Post what you've tried. It will help us help you.

Comment: "SUMA.*?([0-9,]+)" seems to work. You can test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/Fuz6wM/1).

Comment: Conveying more about the format of the input string will improve the answers posted. Is it always "SUMA<space><number>"? Is there ever other text between SUMA and the number? Is the number always the same format (2 digits<comma>2 digits)? Stuff like that.

Comment: the number is always same format but there might be text between SUMA and number. is there any way to not match this text and get only number?

Comment: @fbardamu Have you tried all of the answers? Liam's answer works just fine even if there is a word after SUMA.

Comment: yes i tried all of them

Comment: By adding *there might be more words between SUMA and number* you have no invalidated all the answers you've already been given..

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex*. Simple Substringing and Removing can do it just fine.
Here is something quick I've whipped up.

```
string test = "Ł9CZIA KUOTA PIV 1,21 SUMA 12,36 otóuka 2 | 0350 |tKasa 1";
test = test.Substring(test.IndexOf("SUMA ") + 5);
test = test.Remove(test.IndexOf(' '));
```

Could probably be simplified somehow, but it does the trick. If you need the result to actual be of a `decimal` type, you'll need to convert it of course.

*Note that this doesn't guarantee you'll have a number (for example, if your input is bad), so you'd need to validate that.

Since you edited your post to add the fact that there could be multiple words between SUMA and the number after I posted my answer I won't explicitly handle that here. That is a situation where I believe regex makes much more sense.

Comment: @Liam - Yes it does. Do you mean with taking out that 6 from the original line? Or something else? I may be misinterpreting you.

Comment: @Liam - Also works perfectly fine. Why do you believe these would not work? Any value between `"SUMA "` and the following space will be captured. The way this is lacking compared to regex is that the value wouldn't necessarily be guaranteed to be a number.

Comment: @Liam - I am running this in a console app as we speak. Why are you assuming it will stop at `12124`? Is it the `+ 5` that is throwing you off? If so, you might want to review the documentation for `IndexOf`.

Comment: *"there might be more words between SUMA and number"*

Comment: @RufusL - That was added after most of these answers (including my own) had been posted.

Comment: Sure, just letting you know so you can adjust the answer

Answer (score 1):

If there can be words between SUMA and number, you might match any character zero or more times non greedy `.*?` and then capture in a group `(\d+,\d+)`

[`SUMA.*? (\d+,\d+)`](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=SUMA.*%3f+%28%5cd%2b%2c%5cd%2b%29&i=%c5%819CZIA+KUOTA+PIV+1%2c21+SUMA+12%2c36+ot%c3%b3uka+1%2c1+2+%7c+0350+%7ctKasa+1%0d%0a%c5%819CZIA+KUOTA+PIV+1%2c21+SUMA+test+12%2c36+ot%c3%b3uka+2+%7c+0350+%7ctKasa+1)

```
string pattern = @"SUMA.*? (\d+,\d+)";
string input = @"Ł9CZIA KUOTA PIV 1,21 SUMA test 12,36 otóuka 1,1 2 | 0350 |tKasa 1";
Regex r = new Regex(pattern);
Match match = r.Match(input);                
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]); // 12,36
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/PMIWM36042)

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex `SUMA (\d+,\d+)` ([Regexr link](https://regexr.com/3qmop)) with a capture group (`?<capture>`). Something like:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(@"SUMA (?<capture>\d+,\d+)");
Match match = reg.Match("Ł9CZIA KUOTA PIV 1,21 SUMA 12,36 otóuka 2 | 0350 |tKasa 1");
if (match.Success)
{
    //12,36
    Console.WriteLine(match.Groups["capture"].Value);
}
```

Comment: The`Regex` string should be treated as a literal with the `@` sign: `Regex reg = new Regex(@"SUMA (?<capture>\d+,\d+)");`

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you want find the word **SUMA**, then skip spaces, and then get a number with possible fractional part.

```
/SUMA\s+(\d+(?:,\d+)?)/
```

Comment: there might be more text between SUMA and number. is there any way to get only the number?

Comment: @fbardamu Yes. If this text doesn't contain any digits you can just write `/SUMA[^\d]+(\d+(?:,\d)?)/`.

Answer (score 0):

use code:

```
string str = "Ł9CZIA KUOTA PIV 1,21 SUMA 12,36 otóuka 2 | 0350 |tKasa 1";
int index = str.IndexOf("SUMA");
if (index > -1)
{
      str = str.Substring(index + 5);// SUMA + SPACE char == 4+1 = 5
      int inx = str.IndexOf(" ");
      if (index > -1)
      {
           str = str.Substring(0, inx);
           Console.WriteLine(str.Trim());
      }
}
```

Comment: *"there might be more words between SUMA and number"*

Answer (score 0):

If you need a comma you should use something like that:

```
SUMA\s(\d+,\d+[^\s])
```

Answer (score 0):

use below code :

```
        string str ="Ł9CZIA KUOTA PIV 1,21 SUMA 12,36 otóuka 2 | 0350 |tKasa 1";
        var sentences = new List<String>();

        int position = 0, start = 0;

        do{
            position = str.IndexOf("SUMA", start);
            if (position >= 0){
                str = str.Substring(position).Trim();
                start += 5;

                position = str.IndexOf("SUMA", start);
                if (position >= 0){
                    string _str = str.Substring(0,position).Trim();
                    sentences.Add(_str);
                    str = str.Substring(position).Trim();
                    start = 0;
                }
                else
                    sentences.Add(str);


            }
        } while (position > 0);


        // Extract decimal 
        string pattern = @"(\d+,\d+)";
        Regex r = new Regex(pattern);

        foreach (var sentence in sentences){
                Match match = r.Match(sentence);
                Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1]); 
        }
```